# Open multiple term.js terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssh

How can I open multiple terminal in term.js?

I'm using term.js with ssh2 module.

Eg scheme:

Client -> Open socket and connecto to node.js server -> node.js server connect third party server via ssh2

I can open only open 1 terminal at a time. Is there a logical way to do it?

Code eg:

server.js

```
    io.of('/ssh').on('connection', function (socket) {
    var conn = new ssh();
    conn.on('ready', function() {
        conn.shell(function(err, stream) {
            if(err)
                return socket.emit('data', 'error');

            socket.on('data', function(data) {
                if(stream)
                    stream.write(data.content);
            });

            stream.on('data', function(data) {
                socket.emit('data', data.toString('binary'));
            });
        });
    }).connect({
        host: 'localhost',
        username: 'user',
        password: 'password'
    });
});
```

client.js

```
socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
socket.on('connect', function() {
    term = new Terminal({
        cols: 80,
        rows: 20,
        convertEol: true,
        useStyle: true,
        cursorBlink: false,
        screenKeys: true
    });

    term.on('data', function(data) {
        socket.emit('data', data);
    });

    term.open(document.getElementById('container'));

    socket.on('data', function(data) {
        term.write(data);
    });

    socket.on('disconnect', function() {
        term.destroy();
    });
});
```

if there is a tab workaround for term.js, I will be pleased too.

Answer (score 0):

I made a multiple terminal working but for the system ssh client, I think you can use the same trick.

```
var io = require("socket.io").listen(82);
var pty = require("pty.js");

io.sockets.on("connection", function(socket) {
 var buff = [];

 var term = pty.spawn("/usr/bin/ssh", ["root@localhost"], {
  name: "xterm-256color",
  cols: 120,
  rows: 40,
  cwd: process.env.HOME,
  env: process.env
 });

 term.on("data", function(data) {
  return !socket ? buff.push(data) : socket.emit("data", data);
 });

 while(buff.length) {
  socket.emit("data", buff.shift());
 }

 socket.on("data", function(data) {
  term.write(data);
 });

 socket.on("disconnect", function() {
  socket = null;
  term.kill();
 });
});
```

Comment: I'm able to kill the terminal, but I'm not able to spawn a new one. How do you spawn a new terminal once you have killed the previous one?